# Keep questioning window size in JS?

Tags: javascript

I need to redirect a user to another page after said user logs in on a desktop using the script below (It makes sense if I could explain the project). However this script only works if a user manually changes their screen size while logged in. Ideally once they have logged in, the script would check a users screen size and then initiate the function.

So is there a way to constantly check the screen size and initiate this accordingly?

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 900) {
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use the `if` explicitly after the login as well as having the event listener.  If that doesn't work, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) API adds a listener to the page and triggers whatever function you like when it hits your desired window size.

Try this:

```
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 900px)');

function mqBreakPoint(mediaQuery) {
    if (mediaQuery.matches) window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; 
}

// call on your page load
mqBreakPoint(mediaQuery);

// listen for media query break point
mediaQuery.addListener(mqBreakPoint);
```